# How to quickly fetch a bunch of hyperlinks in Chrome Dev Tool console?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, xpath, google-chrome-devtools, microsoft-edge

For example, I would like to fetch all the model download links from https://huggingface.co/lllyasviel/ControlNet-v1-1/tree/main :
[image]

I opened chrome dev tool, entered Xpath:

```js
> $x("/html/body/div/main/div/section/div[3]/ul/li/a[1]/@href")
< (30) [href, href, href, href, href, href, href, href, href, href, href, href, href, href, href, href, href, href, href, href, href, href, href, href, href, href, href, href, href, href]
```

How can I nicely print all real hrefs so that I could copy paste them into plain text file?

like:

```
https://huggingface.co/lllyasviel/ControlNet-v1-1/resolve/main/.gitattributes
https://huggingface.co/lllyasviel/ControlNet-v1-1/resolve/main/README.md
https://huggingface.co/lllyasviel/ControlNet-v1-1/resolve/main/control_v11e_sd15_ip2p.pth
https://huggingface.co/lllyasviel/ControlNet-v1-1/resolve/main/control_v11e_sd15_ip2p.yaml
...
...
```

Answer (score 0):

Since Chrome's `$x()` utility returns an array, you can *map* it to any format you want.

For example...

```js
const attrs = $x(...);

console.log(attrs.map(({ nodeValue }) => nodeValue).join("\n"));
```

Comment: nodeValue give me relative URI only, how can I concat `baseURI` and `nodeValue` together?

Comment: and what does { nodeValue } mean? I see it extracts the property `nodeValue` from the Objects?

Comment: Oh, I did it by `console.log(attrs.map((a) => "https://huggingface.co"+a.nodeValue).join("\n"));`, thanks!